# How to get return value from another class's function in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, tapku

This is the method from Tapku and I want to call it from the controller

```
- (NSDate*) dateSelected{
if(selectedDay < 1 || selectedPortion != 1) return nil;

TKDateInformation info = [monthDate dateInformationWithTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
info.hour = 0;
info.minute = 0;
info.second = 0;
info.day = selectedDay;
NSDate *d = [NSDate dateFromDateInformation:info timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];


return d;
```

}

And I'm trying to call it like this and convert it to string format.

```
TKCalendarMonthView *tk=[[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] init];
NSDate *date=tk.dateSelected;// How can I call it?With the debug it shows it's null.
NSDateFormatter *selectedDate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[selectedDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSMutableString *stringDate=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[selectedDate stringFromDate: date]]`
```

Comment: NSDate *date= [tk dateSelected];

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: You need to assign value to `selectedDay` and `selectedPortion` in the `TKCalendarMonthView ` object you create. Alternatively, you can pass the values to the function.

Comment: So, tell us, where above was a date selected?

Comment: Did you step through the method in debug mode? Is it being executed?

Comment: Did you check putting nslog inside this what it is returning - (NSDate*) dateSelected ???

Comment: Yes I tried with both debug and nslog it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *date= [tk dateSelected];
```

Makes it a function call (strictly speaking, send the object a message). Dot syntax is for getters/setters only. I strongly suggest reading upon objc basic first.

Comment: But the dot notation will generally work for a parameterless method.  There's another problem.

Comment: Changing the syntax is not gonna help in this case. Parameters in the target function `dateSelected` are not initialised hence this problem is there.